# Create CRUD using .net6

Tags: sharepoint, .net-6.0

> I tried to create CRUD function. I can connect to my SharePoint to see my records, but I need to create CRUD functionalities. Any idea ?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more, what you are trying to accomplish in general?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't have any code, I tried to connect to sharePoint and used CRUD. I'm using C# with .Net6.